# Is there a variant of Lord Grathan's helmet for level 27?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

[image]

Above is the helmet that I am currently trying to find. Is there a variant of the helmet that I can wear as a level 27 juggernaut?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  It looks like the [earliest-craftable version](http://torf.mmo-fashion.com/hypercloth-force-expert-imp/) of this helmet is limited to level 51+, and the [earliest](https://torf.mmo-fashion.com/fractured-bulwarks-mk-3-imp/)-[obtainable](https://torf.mmo-fashion.com/fractured-pummlers-mk-3-imp/) to level 50+.

You should reach 50 pretty quickly, though!  The leveling process has been very streamlined.

Comment: Well sadly I am a preferred status.

Comment: It still won't take more than a few hours.

Comment: No I mean preferred status players cannot advance past level 50.

Comment: Ah, that's not necessarily true.  Most people become Preferred by getting the expansions with a month's subscription and then letting it lapse (which is well worth it IMO).  But, understood!